# How do i make building with levels and production?

Tags: c#, class, oop, console-application

I want to make game, like Tribal Wars, but in console and single player. I have Village class and there I have to make something, which contains building level and according to level is production of the building. I tried to do it with multidimension array, like `building[level, production]` but it haven't worked.
This is full code from class Village (Primary class is Program)

```
class Village
{
    /*
    private int mainBuild = 0;
    private double[] mainBuildCost = new double[20];
    private int woodCutter = 0;
    private double[] woodCutterCost = new double[20];
    private double[] woodCutterProd = new double[20];*/
    public double[,] woodCutter = new double[20, 1];
    private int wood = 50;

    public Village()
    {
        woodCutter[0, 0] = 5;
        for (int lvl = 1; lvl < woodCutter.GetLength(0); lvl++)
        {
            for (int prod = 1; prod <= woodCutter.GetLength(1); prod++)
            {
                woodCutter[lvl, 0] = Math.Round(woodCutter[lvl-1, prod-1])*1.3;
            }
            woodCutter[lvl, 0] = lvl;
            Console.Write(woodCutter);
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, it's really but and doesn't work, but i have no idea, how do I make my plan.

Comment: you want a way to store the production per level of the woodworkers?

Comment: Yes, you can say it like this. And in another function, every second, wood += production.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently. Your production here can be represented as a formula.

Here's a little example:

```
class Village
{
    public double CurrentWood { get; private set; }
    public int WoodLevel { get; private set; }
    public double WoodProduction { get { return WoodLevel * 1.3; } } // Change the formula to your own

    public void Update()
    {
        // Update all your resources in here
        CurrentWood += Production;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks clear and what if i would want change woodProduction according to production of previous level production * 1.3? For example, production on level 1 is 30

Comment: @HonzaSedloň that's a different formula, if you want this, you need something like that: `baseProduction * Math.Pow(1.3, level)`, level being 0 based